# CMake how proper link internal static library for creating another one

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, libraries, static-linking

My main problem is how to link internal static library to be able build other internal static library which needs headers from first one.

I have internal project which include 3 libraries and main which is executable and to build them I need provide some mechanism using CMake to build this project.

My code structure is next:

```
|source:
|--libA
|     include
|        some.hpp
|     src
|        some.cpp
|     CMakeLists.txt 
|--libB
|     include
|     src
|     CMakeList.txt
|--libC
|    include
|    src
|    CMakeLists.txt
|  main.cpp
|  CMakeList.txt
```

Dependencies
libA -> libC (to build libA I need some headers from libC)
libB -> libA i libC (to build libB I need some headers from libA and libC)

I am not very well familiar with CMake, and I want try to use target_link_libraries(libA PRIVATE libC) but it doesn't work,

CMake files for all lib is similar:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project("libA")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC)
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        SRC/*.cpp
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE libC)
```

and main CMake just link this libraries to main and make executables.

At this moment I have problem with bulding libA and libB I don't know how proper link to them for libA how link libC and for libB how link to libC and libA. Maybe I don't need to link them but in some way provide headers from one lib to be able other.

Maybe there is other option how to do this. Thanks for help :)

Example:
folder libC
libC.hpp

```
#include <iostream>

class libC
{
private:
    int m_x;
public:
    libC(int x);
    ~libC();
};
```

libC.cpp

```
#include "libC.hpp"

libC::libC(int x) : m_x{ x }
{
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)

project("libC")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC)
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE USING_${PROJECT_NAME}_LIB)

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        libC.cpp
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/
    
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
)
```

folder libA:
libA.hpp:

```
#include <iostream>

class libA
{
private:
    int m_x;
public:
    libA(int x);
    ~libA();
};
```

libA.cpp:

```
#include "libA.hpp"
#include "libC.hpp"

libA::libA(int x) : m_x{ x }
{
    libC one_more{34};
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)

project("libA")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC)
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE USING_${PROJECT_NAME}_LIB)

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        libA.cpp
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/
    
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC libC)
```

Main folder:
main.cpp:

```
include <iostream>

#include "libA.hpp"
#include "libC.hpp"


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    libA lib{ 54 };
    
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)

project("MaIn")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE libA libC)

add_subdirectory(libA)
add_subdirectory(libC)
```

build step:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"
cmake --build .
[ 33%] Built target libC
[ 50%] Building CXX object libA/CMakeFiles/libA.dir/libA.cpp.o
prj_1/libA/libA.cpp:2:10: fatal error: libC.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "libC.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [libA/CMakeFiles/libA.dir/build.make:76: libA/CMakeFiles/libA.dir/libA.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:145: libA/CMakeFiles/libA.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Comment: `it doesn't work,` this is too esoteric. What exact error message you are receiving? Please post your real code with real cmakelists and post the error description from `make VERBOSE=1` or `cmake --verbose` build. Or, actually create all the files and prepare an [MCVE] and post the exact error message with all the steps to reproduce. Working on "imaginary" code will not help you much - yes, `target_link_libraries` is the way to "proper" link libraries. Still, you have an error in your _real_ code.

Comment: A static library is really just an archive of object files. Linking with a static library is similar to linking with the individual object files. As such, static libraries aren't linked themselves, and they don't include their dependencies. When you link with a static library, you must also link to all its dependencies.

Comment: `I don't know how proper link to them for libA how link libC and for libB how link to libC and libA` Just `target_link_libraries(libA PRIVATE libC) and `target_link_libraries(libB PRIVATE libC libA)`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: With that said, the nice thing about CMake is that it can keep track of dependencies, so your main application target should only need to link with the top-level library, and all its dependencies should be linked as well. But I don't remember if you can use `target_link_libraries` to set up the dependencies, and if you can if you need them to be made `PUBLIC`. You might need to set some [properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html) on the static library to list its dependencies.

Comment: error is that it can't find include headers in libA source code from libC, and I don't want to copy this headers and keep it in both libraries 

libA.cpp:2:10 fatal error: libC.hpp: No such file or directory
2 | #include "libC.hpp"
compilation terminated.

Comment: Quick fix can be if I include headers via path like for ex for libA.cpp
#include "../libC/libC.hpp" , but I want to find cmake mechanism which can help avoid puting such path to include headers because if path will change than I need to make adjustment everywhere . That's why I was thinking about static libraries and than link to them for avoid providing such path for include headers

Comment: A problem is there's no canonical way to organise C++ code, as there is for [some] other languages. I started typing an answer yesterday based on how I organise my code, then deleted it when I realized you're organising yours differently. I don't use separate include directories for my header files, as many projects do. I'm not an expert on using separate include directories -- suggest you find some examples on github -- but my understanding is that in this case you would have a single include directories for all libraries. Then you could add that directory using `include_directories`?